# LockerService: Can't access the DOM of a component on the same namespace

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, locker-service

(Original question after the line)

After some further investigation, it looks like it becomes "SecureComponentRef" because the < th > is inside an aura:iteration, and the aura:iteration takes it into its own namespsace or something ('aura').
 I understand why it does that programatically (everything is being passed as sort of an argument), but I don't understand why it would do that logically, as I should be allowed access to whatever I'm trying to design and is not part of the aura:iteration internal functionality.

---

So we've turned on LockerService a couple of weeks ago, expecting it to be in effect immediately, but came back from the weekend and now a piece of code isn't working.
Based on this post: [component.find(...).getElement not working after Summer 16 release](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127307/component-find-getelement-not-working-after-summer-16-release) , it should've stopped working the moment I activated it had it been the case, but the issue is that both components are on the same namespace (allegedly):

Have an extensible abstract component with this code:

```
    sortRecords: function(component, event, records) {
      <...>
      headerElement = component.find('columnHeaders')[0].getElement();
```

Another component extends it and has this defined:

```
    <th aura:id="columnHeaders" class="{!globalId + '_columnHeaders' + ' slds-is-sortable' + ' slds-is-resizable'}" scope="col" onclick="{!c.sortRecords}" data-name="{!fieldName}">
```

And on that line of code I'm getting the "component.find(...)[0].getElement is not a function" error, because the < th > is now a SecureComponentRef (not sure what it was last week).
Is this not a purpose of having an abstract component? Any other best practice way I should design this?

Comment: Found a workaround/solution to the problem.. posted it as an answer here, which is pretty much the same issue I was facing in different wording:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/129256/31984

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with LockerService. Even though your element is inside an iteration, it should still return a SecureComponent instead of a SecureComponentRef as you've discovered. We're actively working on a fix. You can open a case to track and tell them to link to W-3206803.

Comment: Known issue:  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000183rMQAQ

Comment: @Trevor, I've clicked the "this issue affects me, hope that's good enough" - thankfully I've found a way around it for now - linked to it in my comment to the question. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Fix is scheduled to be released in the next week or so in the .12 patch.